# Angular Redirect to same component

Tags: angular

I have a case where a user goes to `/details;id=1`, in the DetailsComponent, I have a table displaying similar objects, with a button that redirects to `/details;id=x` where x is the id of the object.

When user clicks on the button the URL params updates, but the page remains static (shows details for id=1, but the url params is x)

The `(click)` handler of the button is:

```
goToDetails(id: number): void {
    this.router.navigate ( [ '/details', { id: id } ] );
}
```

How do I make Angular "refresh" the component?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Angular provides three types of route parameters: 1) Required parameters. 2) Optional parameters. 3) Query parameters.

The syntax you are using is for optional parameters. You may want to instead use required parameters. The syntax would then look like this:

```
this.router.navigate ( [ '/details', id ] );
```

In the component, you can then read the parameters like this:

```
this.route.params.subscribe(
   params => {
      let id = params['id'];
      <Add your code here>
   }
);
```

I normally put this code into the ngOnInit lifecycle hook method.

The route configuration would look like this:

```
{ path: 'product/:id', component: ProductDetailComponent }
```

You can see a complete example here: https://github.com/DeborahK/Angular-Routing

Comment: how do I set up my routes to handle required parameters?

Comment: Updated my answer to include the configuration.

Comment: You could so something similar with optional parameters, but it seems like for a detail page that the id is *required*.

Comment: Does it have to be a subscription? With optional parameters I was able to set the Id to the route params in the constructor. Is there a similar way to do it with this configuration?

Comment: Based on your title: 'redirect to same component', then yes, you need to subscribe. Otherwise you wont be able to route to the same component and read the current parameters each time. If you only read the parameters one time and don't route to the same component, then no. You can get the values without using the observable.

Comment: thank you so much. Will definitely check out your course!